# Can you make an uncloseable, unleavable, Java application?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Is there a way to make sure that a user cannot close or leave my Swing application? I've tried to make it fullscreen, but you can still Alt-Tab away from it—and besides, that doesn't work well when you decide to use JOptionPane's dialogs.

So, is there any way to make a user use only this one Java program on a device?

Edit: Some people wonder about the purpose. The application is supposed to be sorta "embedded" into the handheld device (which runs under Windows), so the users of the device will use it as we intend it to be used—for example, that they won't play Freecells or do something worse instead of doing the actual work. Have you seen ticketing kiosks? They are locked down pretty well, you can't just close their big flashy GUI and get to the Windows desktop!

Comment: not sure but I think we can capture button combination `alt+tab` and ignore it.

Comment: Not on the Java side - you will need to setup up the OS, so that it doesn't respond to alt-tab and the like..

Comment: No you cannot capture alt+tab since the OS intercepts it before it gets handed to the JVM

Comment: Which operating system are you targeting? The solution would depend on where this is run.

Comment: why do you want an unleavable app that, will just annoy people...

Comment: unleavable apps smell malicious intentions (a.k.a malware) ;)

Comment: Perhaps he is developing software for a company, like a touch screen register (for example).  Such software runs on an underlying operating system, but it should be uncloseable and unleavable.  The user should never even know the OS exists.

Answer (score 7):

Okay @Daniel showed you how to make a Java app un-closeable (+1 to him) by calling:

`JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`

on the `JFrame` instance.

To make sure you cant leave it i.e by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> etc you may want to do this (applies to windows only):

1) Disable TaskManager/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> by:

- Setting registry key:

  > HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System/DisableTaskMgr = 1

  via reg script or cmd.exe.

2) To disable all shortcuts together like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> etc see [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5937-windows-key-shortcuts-enable-disable.html)    (Download/use the `*.reg` script and execute it via `cmd`).

Comment: But the point is to do the whole thing programatically, isn't it?

Comment: @Rempelos Maybe I'm misunderstanding, Uhm but you can, simply call `cmd.exe` using `Runtime.exec(...)` or `ProcessBuilder` with the parameters of the registry script path, alternatively OP may look into REG ADD command of `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 3):

Uncloseable yes, you can use `setDefaultCloseOperation();` and pass it `JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`

**Example:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class app extends JFrame {
    app(String title, int height, int width)
    {
        super (title);
        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
class program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        app myApp = new app("Hello", 350, 750);
    }
}
```

Comment: This covers unclosable but not unleavable.

Comment: You're right but I don't know if the other can be achieved personally

Comment: @Daniel +1 nice example. Though I'd suggest not extending the `JFrame` class and always start your GUI on a `Event-Dispatch-Thread`; and yes of course it can, maybe not in pure java (but using some techniques see my answer)...

Answer (score 3):

We do something similar with a POS application, but we cheat a little bit. While making use of Full Screen helps a lot, we found users could STILL exit the application.

In the end, we created a Windows Service (yes, we run on Windows) that automatically RESTARTS as soon as it's closed. So, you can see the Windows desktop (we removed the icons) for a split second, but then the app pops up again. The benefit of this is also that we can update the JAR file remotely, from the intranet, and all the users need to do is push a button that closes the system, it restarts automatically and is updated. We wanted to use WebStart, but had problems integrating it with our wrapper.

The wrapper itself is a Python application that just starts the JVM and application, compiled to an EXE. Simple, but effective.

The net effect is a closable application that will automatically start itself again. Good enough for our use where we need to user to be able to do one thing and one thing only. Giving the startup credentials for the application Admin privileges, and the users just a normal account, took care of the pesky 'alt-ctrl-del' users as well. You can't kill a process that's got higher access rights than yourself.

If you don't feel like writing your own wrapper, give http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/product-overview.html a whirl, it looks like a brilliant product.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch pretty much any keystrokes you like (and have them ignored) in your app, so Alt-Tab can be fixed. The one key combination that an application can **never** (ish) handle itself, is the Ctrl+Alt+Delete, which is hooked into the kernel in many operating systems for security reasons. As a side note: this is why many login screens ask you to hit C+A+D before entering your username and password.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen some (malware) apps that somehow prevent you from using Ctrl+Alt+Delete though

Comment: It's possible, just not in pure Java.

Comment: @Rempelos Malware authors are clever than the developers of Windows :P

Comment: @DavidKroukamp that probably explains it then... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a maximized window that can't be unmaximized or closed.  You'd also have to trap certain keystrokes such as CTRL+SHIFT+ESCAPE, ALT+TAB, WIN+[anything], various Fn keys, and you'd have to do something to prevent CTRL+ALT+DELETE from working (Either from showing the task manager or from bringing up the blue options screen in windows vista or 7.

I believe there are windows API calls that can change the behavior of CTRL+ALT+DELETE somehow but have no idea what they are.  A good place to investigate would be Sysinternals Process Explorer, which has the functionality to replace the task manager.  Figure out how it does this, then replicate it.