# How to make my java program run on its own and disable windows key, cmd, etc

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have created a java program in netbeans. It's an election program so users can login, using sql functions, and vote, etc.

No problems with the creation of the buttons, methods, testing, database etc.

Currently Im setting the java program with a jframe background as a fullscreen with all my other jframe's ontop (thanks to .setAlwaysOntTop())  - NOW.....

I want to run this program at my school, so lots of learners will be using the program to vote for an Student Representative Council. Now I want to disable the start button on keyboard, disable the ability to use CTR + ALT + DELETE to go to task manager.

How would I go about to do this.

Thanks in advance. If you want the code - please send me an email - although its not really necessary.

Divvie

Comment: You could always brute force it, I mean an infinite loop using the robot class always releasing the keys on a separate thread.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't disable c-a-del, period.

Comment: You can stop the explorer task from running which will disable the start menu and task bar.  ctrl-alt-del is part of the OS, and cannot be disabled though.

Comment: This is operating system dependent, and not easily done from within Java.  you should reconfigure windows into kiosk mode first, and then run your program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you make an uncloseable, unleavable, Java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782882/can-you-make-an-uncloseable-unleavable-java-application)

Comment: As far as I know `Ctrl+Alt+Delete` can never be intercepted by user-level programs.

Answer (score 2):

Windows in Kiosk mode is the best idea, but I might also suggest trying to find a machine with a pen input and don't provide a keyboard, or only provide a mouse and not a keyboard.  This should be pretty safe although you'll have to test for edge cases --Litterally, like running to the "edge" of the window and trying to click/drag stuff :)